# Finding Lagrange Polynomials from LU-Decomposition

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

The linear system $V p = f$ can be solved to find coefficients of the polynomial $P(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 $ that interpolates the points $(-1,f_1), (2,f_2), (1,f_3), (0,f_4)$, where $V$ is the Vandermonde matrix, $p$ contains the coefficients, and $f$ contains the function outputs. See below:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&1&-1\\
1&2&4&8\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_0\\
a_1\\
a_2\\
a_3\\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1\\
f_2\\
f_3\\
f_4\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

One can use $LU$-decomposition of the Vandermonde matrix to solve this system for any given coefficients of $a_i$ for $i = 1,\dots, 4$ whereby:
$$ L = \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
1&2/3&1&0\\
1&1/3&1&1
\end{bmatrix}, \, \, \, \,
U = \begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&1&-1\\
0&3&3&9\\
0&0&-2&-4\\
0&0&0&2
\end{bmatrix}  $$

My question is: how could one calculate the Lagrange polynomials to interpolate this polynomial $\textbf{without}$ explicitly using the formula for the Lagrange Polynomials? I am told this is possible using the results from the $LU$-decomposition, however I am not sure where the link between the two methods are? Might anyone have any suggestions how this would be possible?

Comment: It is weird that you gave yourself the solution without realizing it ! The coefficients of the polynomial are the unknowns $a_k$, obtained from the $f_l$ by $LU$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think the OP objective is to determine the coefficients of the Lagrange polynomials, not of the interpolating polynomial.

Comment: If you mean the individual polynomials, set $f_l=\delta_{kl}$, which amounts to solve $LUA=I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lagrange polynomials, $L_i(x)$ are in this case polynomials of degree $\leq 3$ satisfying $L_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$. You can use the $LU$ decomposition to solve the systems $V p = e_i$, yielding the coefficients of $L_i(x)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Can you expand upon this? I've been told that one particular Lagrange Polynimal is given as such: $$L_1(x) = -x/3 + x^2/2 - x^3/6$$ How would one obtain that polynomial?

Comment: You would solve your system using the RHS $f = (1,0,0,0)$, and you would obtain $a_0 = 0, a_1 = -\frac 13, a_2 =\frac 12, a_3 = -\frac 16$.